Uploading images with grapejs and laravel
While using grapejs and laravel, I have issue with uploading images. My problem is defining folder while uploading images. I want to upload the images in public/upload/images and the images in page should have right path like /upload/images/1.jpg. any idea?
I tried:
assetManager: {
   assets: {
       upload: '/upload/images',
       uploadName: 'files',
       src: "/upload/images",
       width: 400 ,
       height: 400,
   },
   src: "/upload/images",
},

but it is not working.

upload , src are full urls. then you are missing the type: 'image'. refs1 & ref2
